# Low battery indicator @ 3.6V

Tags: batteries, indicator

I'm trying to make a simple low-battery indicator(3.6V 18650 LiIon) that will turn on red LED. I already tried something(schematic is below) but it doesn't work.
I already have zener diodes(1/2W, 2.7V), and op. amps([UA741CN DIP-8 UA741 LM741 ST](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-10Pcs-UA741CN-DIP-8-UA741-LM741-ST-Operational-Amplifiers-OP-AMP-IC-/331496220557?hash=item4d2eb6e78d:g:j5UAAOSwKIpWFOIE)), and of course resistors. Threshold voltage is 3.6V(+/- 0.1V).

[image]

Comment: How are you supplying the 741 rails?

Comment: @jonk With 5V(from step-up booster). Op. amp has VCC at pin 7, and GND at pin 4.

Comment: You could use this circuit from Linear Technologies: http://m.eet.com/media/1138335/17412-figure_1.pdf
Basically, an LTC 1540.

Comment: I think you might need to use a different op-amp. The basic idea appears sound. Maybe you just need to use a single-supply op-amp, or a comparator instead of an op-amp. The 741 doesn't work correctly when powered from a 5V supply. You may also want to add some hysteresis (large resistor from output back to non-inverting input, plus add a series resistor between D2 and non-inverting input).

Comment: Given that the 741 will only swing within 2V of the rails with that load (on a good day), it's not surprising your circuit doesn't do what you'd expect. 5V - 2V - 2V = 1V. Use a comparator or a rail to rail op amp.

Comment: @uint128_t What if I give 12V to op. amp?

Comment: It might work. Ideally, you would run the 741 on a bipolar supply. The easiest solution to your problem is a comparator. Get yourself an LM339, they're dirt cheap.

Comment: @uint128_t Thanks! But which op. amp should I buy, if I don't want to change schematic?

Comment: @uint128_t LM339 is quad. I don't have much space to use, so I need one single.

Comment: @SilvioCro Space-constrained and you're using a 741? Well then. There are scads of single comparators in SOT-23-5 or even SC-70-5, take a look on Digikey. For instance: [AP331A](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP331A.pdf)